# placeholders for regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm pretty new to regular expressions, and i don't really know how to use them correctly yet.
As input i have a string, in which i want to look for a certain pattern, let's say a word enclosed in !, like this: "Hello, my name is !John!". Now i want to replace the substring inside with something different. How do i look for the substring without knowing what is inside?

String str = "I don't !know! how to do this";

str = str.replace("!placeholder!", "X");

Just like that.

Comment: Does the word between the `!` matter? E.g. can you have multiple placeholders, and the replacement text is chosen depending on what the placeholder word is? Like `!A! is better than !B!`?

Comment: it doesn't, it won't be any special characters,simply letters which i want to capitalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replaceAll("!.*!", "X")` would be a way to do it. There are however many different "placeholders" and special characters you should be aware of (at least to escape them). In this instance I used `.` to match any character and `*` to signify that I want any number of those. The expression then reads as "replace all exclamation points, followed by any number of characters and ending in another exclamation point with the letter X".

That would also replace the exclamation points, so perhaps you want to write `str.replaceAll("!.*!", "!X!")`. Or maybe you don't want to replace the string "!!" so you'd use "!.+!". But to explore all the possibilities, you should really read some tutorial like this one: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: `.*` is too greedy, and wouldn't work right if there is another `!` later in the text. You could use `.*?` or `[^!]*` instead. You might also want to use `+` instead of `*`, so a `!!` in the text doesn't get processed.

Comment: @Andreas True, but as the person asking the question doesn't even know that matching symbols in regular expressions exist, I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. My solution is sufficient for all the examples he provided and answered the question. If you still disagree, then I don't have problem with you modifying the answer. Then I feel like the best expression would be `\w+?` as he explicitly mentioned having a word inside.

Comment: @Andreas also if you read my answer carefully, I even mention `!.+!`

Comment: @veprolet it's really helpful, thank you. Now i know that there are no special characterse in between so i don't have to worry about another "!" for example, it simply will be letters that i want to capitalize differently.

Comment: @quizz if you'll use something robust like toUpperCase(), then the `!.+?!` is probably what you're looking for as this method considers the locale and ignores special characters anyway. I'm glad I could help, but don't forget to mark as accepted / upvote the answers that answered your question or helped. It makes searching for relevant answers easier for other people... and I'll get a rush from the green tick...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
!\w+!\s*
```

or,

```
!\w+!
```

might simply work OK for those examples.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nqgsFb/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "!\\w+!\\s*";
        final String string = "I don't !know!     how to do this\n"
             + "Hello, my name is !John!           ";
        final String subst = "something_else ";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
I don't something_else how to do this
Hello, my name is something_else
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/r9GCH7/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/r9GCH7/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It is supposed to *replace* with something else, not *remove*, so you don't want to include trailing spaces in that regex.